# select node based on other node in certain order

Tags: xslt

```
<command>abc</command>
<Pset name="X_number">
<var name="Y_name">A</var>
<var name="Y_num">6</var>
<var name="Z_name">C</var>
</Pset>
<Pset name="T_num">
<var name="T_num">1</var>
</Pset>
<Pset name="T_num">
<var name="T_num">2</var>
</Pset>
<Pset name="T_status">
<var name="T_status">U</var>
</Pset>
<Pset name="T_status">
<var name="T_status">V</var>
</Pset>
<Pset name="end_matching">
</Pset>

<Pset name="X_number">
```

We have to get following structure out of it :

```
        <Event>

        <module_num>A</module_num> <here module_num corrosponds to <var name="Y_name">A</var> and display value of Y_name)

        <Tnumber>1</Tnumber> (here TNumber(you can give any name, I kept Tnumber to keep it simple) corresponds to first Pset of T_Num and get the value from <var name="T_num">1</var>)
<Tstatus>U</Tstatus> (here Tstatus corresponds to first Pset of T_status and get the value from <var name="T_Status">U</var>)           
        </Event>

    <Event>

    <module_num>A</module_num> <here module_num is same as first Event set>

    Tnum>2</Tnum> ( Here also it is second one , and there can be multiple )
    <Tstatus>V</Tstatus>
    </Event>
```

Module_num will reamin common to all event which originates from X_number and Tstatus and Tnum will be related based on their position, we have to iterate through all the T_num/ T_status before start of another X_number .

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kPsetByPrecX_number"
             match="Pset[@name[.='T_num' or .='T_status']]"
             use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::Pset[@name='X_number'][1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="t">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Pset[@name='X_number']"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Pset[@name='X_number']">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent-group"
                      select="key('kPsetByPrecX_number',generate-id())"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vCurrent-group[@name='T_num']">
            <xsl:with-param name="pModule" select="var[@name='Y_name']"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pStatus"
                            select="$vCurrent-group[@name='T_status']"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Pset[@name='T_num']">
        <xsl:param name="pModule"/>
        <xsl:param name="pStatus" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="vPosition" select="position()"/>
        <Event>
            <module_num>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pModule"/>
            </module_num>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="(.|$pStatus[$vPosition])/var"/>
        </Event>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="var">
        <xsl:element name="{translate(@name,'_','')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<t>
    <command>abc</command>
    <Pset name="X_number">
        <var name="Y_name">A</var>
        <var name="Y_num">6</var>
        <var name="Z_name">C</var>
    </Pset>
    <Pset name="T_num">
        <var name="T_num">1</var>
    </Pset>
    <Pset name="T_num">
        <var name="T_num">2</var>
    </Pset>
    <Pset name="T_status">
        <var name="T_status">U</var>
    </Pset>
    <Pset name="T_status">
        <var name="T_status">V</var>
    </Pset>
    <Pset name="end_matching"></Pset>
    <Pset name="X_number"/>
</t>
```

Output:

```
<t>
    <Event>
        <module_num>A</module_num>
        <Tnum>1</Tnum>
        <Tstatus>U</Tstatus>
    </Event>
    <Event>
        <module_num>A</module_num>
        <Tnum>2</Tnum>
        <Tstatus>V</Tstatus>
    </Event>
</t>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: I would work with `<xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::Pset[@name='T_status'][number($vPosition)]" mode="out"/>` then you do not need kStatusByNumber nor vNumber; what do you think?

Comment: @mousio: That would rely on the existence of one `Pset[@name='T_status']` for every `Pset[@name='T_num']` because otherwise not using `Pset[@name='X_number']` as anchor might result in a wrong output. Besides that, it would be also a good solution.

Comment: Alejandro/Mousio : Thanks for looking into this matter, I will explore it to fit into my requirement , in case of any issues I will get back to you guys.

Comment: I find it a little complicated to understand , I am trying to capture just three element in following format <Event > <Y_num></Y_num> <Tnum></Tnum> <Tstatus>U</Tstatus> <Event > I tried to do it on my xml , It does match Tnum and Tstat . I was trying to get above structure but not able to do so because of my limited knowledge on XSLT. I will be thankful if you guys can suggest how to accomplish

Comment: @Xslguy: No problem. Just provide a exact desired output for the input sample you've posted (and correct that to be well formed).

Comment: Alejandro : I have edited existing question to reflect exact structure which I am looking for , I will be thankful if you can help me on same regards

Comment: this works like charm , only thing I had to change is to add index in the key [1] , as module_num was not getting updated and it was repeating the first X_number module_num. I am thankful for  this help and appreciate your excellent XSL writing skills.

Comment: @Xslguy: You are right. I've missed the positional predicate.